# How to we simulate a file upload in jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm writing a test using jest to test my reactJS components. I need to simulate a file upload in jest to test my reactjs component. Does anyone know how? Here's my code

```
<div className="add-graphic-card-cta">
                <input
                    ref={inputRef}
                    className='add-graphic-card-file'
                    type="file"
                    accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,image/jpeg,image/png"
                    onChange={this._handleChooseGraphicChange.bind(this)}
                    onDrop={(e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }}
                />
                <Button
                    className="add-graphic-card-button"
                    label={this.props.intl.formatMessage({ id: 'ccl-graphic-verb-add' })}
                    variant="cta"
                    onClick={this.onFileUpload.bind(this, inputRef)} />
            </div>
```

Here's the test

```
 it('upload a file', () => {
            const fn = jest.fn();
            const header = shallowWithIntl(<LibraryManagerAddGraphicCard onClick={fn} />).dive();

            header.find('.add-graphic-card-button').simulate('click', {
                preventDefault: jest.fn(),
                stopPropagation: jest.fn()
            });
```

Comment: What you are trying to test after simulate upload file ?

Comment: I want to trigger the onchange above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not actually tried this one out, but I suppose you can simulate the `onChange` event to mock the file upload event:

```
header.find('.add-graphic-card-file').simulate('change', {
  target: {
    files: ['file.jpg'],   
  },
});
```

This should cause the `_handleChooseGraphicChange` method to be triggered.